# Kafka concurrency config Spring setConsumerTaskExecutor and setConcurrency

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

What is different between setConsumerTaskExecutor() and setConcurrency() in spring kafka?
What happend if the maxpool size of ConsumerTaskExecutor different with setConcurrency value?

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor customExecutor= new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
exec.setCorePoolSize(3);
exec.setMaxPoolSize(6);

ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>();

factory.setConcurrency(10);
factory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerTaskExecutor(customExecutor);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`concurrency`:

> The maximum number of concurrent KafkaMessageListenerContainers running. Messages from within the same partition will be processed sequentially.

`ConsumerTaskExecutor`:

> Set the executor for threads that poll the consumer.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.html#getConcurrency()

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ContainerProperties.html#setConsumerTaskExecutor(org.springframework.core.task.AsyncListenableTaskExecutor)

---

In other words, `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainer` creates 1 or more `KafkaMessageListenerContainers` based on `concurrency`. And every `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` shares the `ContainerProperties`, using `ConsumerTaskExecutor` to run a `ListenerConsumer` which delegate to a `Kafka consumer` to do a poll.

Comment: I confuse with term "that poll the consumer" does it mean consumer receive message from broker and a threadpool execute messages,  as my example, does it have 10 consumer and max 6 thread will process message ?

Comment: In your example, if you only create **1** `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainer`, based on your `setConcurrency=10`, it will then create 10 `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`s = 10 threads (1 consumer per thread). And each `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` will use your `customExecutor` to start a thread. Since your pool size = 6, you're going to get `Consumer thread failed to start - does the configured task executor have enough threads to support all containers and concurrency?` from the 7th consumer.

Comment: Threads are not shared across consumers - each consumer needs a dedicated thread.

Comment: Yes, since we have 10 consumers so we need 10 threads (1 consumer per thread).

Comment: setConsumerTaskExecutor(org.springframework.core.task.AsyncListenableTaskExecutor) is removed as of latest version.